HuggingFace Transformers generation not deterministic
I have a strange issue when trying to decode from a Lora model I've trained. args.checkpoint is a Lora model trained on top of TinyLlama. When I decode using this, I expect it to give me the same result every time (greedy decoding) but as you can see the results are slightly off:
if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = get_args()
    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(args.checkpoint)
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(args.model)
    tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
    device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    model = model.to(device)
    p = "Dialogue: #Person1#: This Olympic park is so big!\n#Person2#: Yes. Now we are in the Olympic stadium, the center of this park.\n#Person1#: Splendid! When is it gonna be finished?\n#Person2#: The whole stadium is to be finished this June.\n#Person1#: How many seats are there in the stand?\n#Person2#: Oh, there are 5000 seats in total.\n#Person1#: I didn ' t know it would be so big!\n#Person2#: It is! Look there, those are the tracks. And the jumping pit is over there.\n#Person1#: Ah... I see. Hey, look the sign here, No climbing.\n#Person2#: We put many signs with English translations for foreign visitors.\n\nSummary:"
    inputs = tokenizer(
        [p],
        return_tensors="pt",
        return_token_type_ids=False,
    ).to(device)  

    for i in range(1, 10): #repeat 
        response = model.generate(
            **inputs,
            max_new_tokens=32,
            do_sample=False, #greedy
            return_dict_in_generate=True,
            eos_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id,
            pad_token_id=tokenizer.pad_token_id,
        )
        decoded_output = tokenizer.decode(
            response["sequences"][0],
            skip_special_tokens=True,
        )  
        res = decoded_output[len(p) :]  # remove prompt from output
        print(f"try {i}: {res}")

The result is (please scroll to the right):
try 1:  #Person1# and #Person2# are talking about the Olympic stadium. #Person1# thinks it is so big.
try 2:  #Person1# and #Person2# are talking about the Olympic stadium. #Person1# thinks it is so big.
try 3:  #Person1# and #Person2# are talking about the Olympic stadium. #Person1# thinks it is so big.
try 4:  #Person1# and #Person2# are talking about the Olympic stadium. #Person1# thinks it is so big.
try 5:  #Person1# and #Person2# are talking about the Olympic stadium. #Person1# thinks it is so big.
try 6:  #Person1# and #Person2# are talking about the Olympic stadium. #Person1# thinks it is so big.
try 7:  #Person1# and #Person2# are talking about the Olympic stadium. #Person2# tells #Person1# that the Olympic stadium is
try 8:  #Person1# and #Person2# are talking about the Olympic stadium. #Person1# thinks it is so big.
try 9:  #Person1# and #Person2# are talking about the Olympic stadium. #Person2# tells #Person1# that the Olympic stadium is

If I wrap the generation code with autocast to lower precision the results are more varied:
try 1:  #Person1# and #Person2# are talking about the Olympic stadium. #Person1# is very excited about it.
try 2:  #Person1# and #Person2# are talking about the Olympic stadium. #Person1# is very excited about the Olympic stadium.
try 3:  #Person1# and #Person2# are talking about the Olympic stadium. #Person1# is very excited about it.
try 4:  #Person1# and #Person2# are talking about the Olympic stadium. #Person1# is very excited about it.
try 5:  #Person1# and #Person2# are talking about the Olympic stadium. #Person1# is very excited about the Olympic stadium.
try 6:  #Person1# and #Person2# are talking about the Olympic stadium. #Person1# is very excited about the Olympic stadium.
try 7:  #Person1# and #Person2# are talking about the Olympic stadium. #Person1# is very excited about the Olympic stadium.
try 8:  #Person1# and #Person2# are talking about the Olympic stadium. #Person1# is very excited about the Olympic stadium.
try 9:  #Person1# and #Person2# are talking about the Olympic Park. #Person1# is very excited about the Olympic Park.

Is this expected? How can I ensure deterministic decoding? TIA

try calling model.eval()

yikes! I should have known that! thanks, that fixed it!

What is the base model before you tune it?
